# Call function in content script from background script in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to call a function in my content.js from background.js. How do I do this?

Content.js

```
function foo() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

Background.js

```
main();
```

Comment: You can't. Those are separate processes. Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) instead.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that with no luck (I'm a newbie). Any tips on how I can do it with messaging?

Comment: Examine [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples). Also use devtools to debug the various parts of chrome extensions by setting breakpoints, examining variables, stepping through the code.